# uncoditioned Count(*) vs System tables

Tags: sql-server, optimization, count

A collegue of mine show me than, to count a record of a table, the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW [SPR].[TablesCount]

AS

SELECT     s.name cSchema,
           t.name cTable,
           sum(p.rows) eRowCount
FROM       sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
ON         s.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN SYS.partitions p
ON         p.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE      p.index_id < 2
GROUP BY   s.name,
           t.name
```

performs dramatically faster than a regular

```
select count(*) from table
```

why this? shouldn't the db engine be optimized to follow the shortest path always?
What's the drawback in the system tables view solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value stored in the metadata is not guaranteed to be correct. [`DBCC UPDATEUSAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188414.aspx) can be used to correct this when it happens (less likely since SQL Server 2000)

Also it is not transactionally consistent. You can read a count value updated by an uncommitted transaction.

And it is possible for these values to be manually updated as well.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(X INT)

UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.YourTable WITH ROWCOUNT = 1000000

SELECT     sum(p.rows) eRowCount
FROM       sys.partitions p
WHERE      P.object_id =object_id('dbo.YourTable') AND p.index_id < 2
```

Comment: two good points, the second one we guessed, but the first one was just suspected