# Is COUNT(*) indexed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I want to know just for curiosity that, does `Select Count(*) from SomeTableName` also traverses all the rows of the database as that of `Select * from SomeTableName`?

Or is there any other count field available in database's metadata that updates itself each time a row is added or deleted? And that field is accessed by the former query.

Also I want to know that which of the both queries is faster and how much?

Comment: how can db keep track of count? what if you request count with filter where?

Comment: `count(*)` is fine, `select *` is not

Comment: @ArsenMkrt then it will only count data the satisfy the condition

Comment: not a dup @Bridge, this question asks if count * tarverse the table or not

Comment: @bew, but should it traverse the table for that or not?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt You're right, I think I need a coffee - close vote retracted :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   SomeTableName
```

will always count all rows. Though (unlike `SELECT *`) it does not have to read all columns and can use the narrowest (non filtered) index available to do so.

Unlike MySQL (MyISAM engine) it does not retrieve the value from metadata.

A rowcount value is available in the metadata and can be retrieved from [`sys.partitions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17446047/73226) but this is never used for `COUNT` queries and isn't always accurate.