# Counting the number of rows in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a better way instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement to count the number of records in table?

Sometimes we have to count billions of records  from temporary tables that are imported using bcp query.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069237/fastest-way-to-count-exact-number-of-rows-in-a-very-large-table

Comment: Thanks @R.S , I looked into it, I'll check the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to filter, the following query works well:

```
SELECT sum(rows) FROM SYS.PARTITIONS WHERE object_id=object_id('MY_TABLE') and index_id in(0,1)
```

That checkes the number of rows sql server is storing for that object.  It can't return any data with the count, and there is no way to include a group by or where.

Comment: Thanks Vulcronos it is really a fast line of code. Earlier I was using  SELECT rows FROM sysindexes WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('table_name') AND indid < 2.

Answer (score 1):

Using `count(*)` or `count(some_column)` is the fastest way to check for a tables record count.

Comment: I've always done count(primaryKey) because I thought the "*" would add some overhead.  But, I'm not positive.

Comment: `count(*)` and `count(some_column)` are not equivalent if the column is nullable.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) statement makes a full table scan to return the total table's row count which can take an extremely long time for large tables, ya its good to count primary key, but here I am about records that touches billion count. @L_7337

Comment: @Parshii - You can get a figure that is likely pretty accurate from the metadata. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069288/73226) linked to already by R.S.

Comment: @MartinSmith: So is it normally better to use `Count(*)` instead of `Count(SomeColumn)` because the column could be nullable(now or in future)? Will sql-server automatically use the "cheapest" column if i pick one that is not nullable(like the PK-Column or any other) or if i use `*`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I use `COUNT(*)` anyway as there is no benefit of using a column name (even the PK or other `NOT NULL` column) and it is shorter and (IMO) clearer. It would be more defensive as well for that reason. And yes `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(PK)` all get the same plan (and show up as `COUNT(*)` in the plan) and SQL Server will use the narrowest index available to do the `COUNT`.

Comment: @MartinSmith I like your last comment, I'll be searching more on how to increase the count speed. And I checked the link you posted in comments also. I'll be back soon to see good answers or I'll post If I found one.

Comment: @Parshii - The only options are to use the figure from the metadata if you can live [with the possible inaccuracies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446002/uncoditioned-count-vs-system-tables/17446047#17446047) or use `COUNT`. And the only thing you can do to optimise `COUNT` on a `#temp` table is to provide a narrow index.

Comment: What about this query, I think its fine. SELECT rows FROM sysindexes WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('table_name') AND indid < 2 @MartinSmith. Your comments on it?