# Retrieve count from query using joins which has billions of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I found a faster way to get the count but only 1 table can be specified.

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint, rows) 
FROM sysindexes 
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('table_name') 
  AND indid < 2
```

Is there a way to use the above query to when we are using joins.

Ex: to get the count of this query -

```
 Select t1.col1, t2.col1 
 from t1 
 join t2 on t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446002/uncoditioned-count-vs-system-tables

Answer (score 0):

No.

The sysindexes query you show is using *metadata* to return the *estimated* row count for the table. It is not necessarily up to date; it can even be lied to (See the link from @Ivan-starostin).

To accomplish your join requires relating two tables and counting the results of that relation. This is not even theoretically possible using metadata; it requires looking at actual data.

Comment: Ok, Got it. Is there a way to find the row count faster when 2 tables are used along with some filter conditions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope. The phrase "filter conditions" AUTOMATICALLY says you need to look at the data.